# C# Get pSID,string SID from SidStart ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE

Tags: c#, winapi

I was trying to get pSID from SidStart value of ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE structure and could not get it for some time.

I found [PInvoke for DWORD-aligned handles to memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647374/pinvoke-for-dword-aligned-handles-to-memory), but unfortunately I cannot add comments just yet.

The person gets the pSid from ACE pointer offset by 8 as follows (don't mind the "deniedAceIntPtr")

```
IntPtr tempSid = IntPtr.Add(deniedAceIntPtr, 8);
```

My question is, where does the 8 come from?

Is it because SidStart in ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE comes after ACE_HEADER and ACCESS_MASK which are both of 4 bytes? So 4+4=8 and SidStart starts after those two at the IntPtr address of the ACE?

Getting the pSid and later SidString using ConvertSidToStringSidW works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [ACCESS_DENIED_ACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-access_denied_ace) structure, You can refer to **SidStart** directly And Yes, `sizeof`([ACE_HEADER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-ace_header#syntax))+`sizeof`([ACCESS_MASK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/access-mask))=8BYTE.

Comment: Yeah, I had SidStart in the form of UInt32, but had no idea how to get an actual SID from that. Offsetting the pointer by those 8 bytes gave me a pointer to SID and then I could convert that to SID string.
Thanks for confirming.